# When should I start drawing on SurfaceView?

Tags: android, surfaceview

I use a SurfaceView to create a marquee feature, but sometimes after the drawing thread in SurfaceView starts running, the UI thread is blocked, my touch on the BACK or MENU button is not dispatched, and an **ANR** is produced. This happens now and then.

I guess it is because the drawing in SurfaceView starts **too early**(of course I ensure the drawing happens between `surfaceCreated()` and `surfaceDestroyed()`), I *guess* the drawing thread should starts after something fully initialized, maybe something related to Activity?

When I add `Thread.sleep(100)` before the code that actually uses `Canvas` returned by `SurfaceHolder.lockCanvas()` to start drawing, the problem *almost* disappears, it still happens, but the frequency is low. If I make the drawing thread sleep longer enough before actually drawing something on the canvas, the problem never occurs again.

It looks like I should start drawing after **something** is fully initialized, but I have no idea about what that something is.

This SurfaceView is used as a normal View that is put in the layout file, the following is the code used to draw on the surface.

```
public void run() {
    try {
        // this is extremely crucial, without this line, surfaceView.lockCanvas() may
        // produce ANR from now and then. Looks like the reason is that we can not start
        // drawing on the surface too early
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (Exception e) {}

    while (running) {
        Canvas canvas = null;
        try{

            long ts = System.currentTimeMillis();

            canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            if (canvas != null) {
                synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                    doDraw(canvas);
                }

                ts = System.currentTimeMillis() - ts;
                if (ts < delayInterval) {
                    Thread.sleep(delayInterval - ts);
                }
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // do nothing
        } finally {
            if (canvas != null)
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any other synchronization on `surfaceHolder` object in your code? And anyway you should call `Thread.sleep` after `unlockCanvasAndPost`, not between `lockCanvas` and `unlockCanvasAndPost`.

Comment: Oh, no! You are the savior! When I put `Thread.sleep` after `unlockCanvasAndPost`, the problem never occurs again, and now I don't need to sleep at the start of the loop. Please post that as the answer, I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't call `Thread.sleep` between `SurfaceHolder.lockCanvas` and `SurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost`, it should be called only after canvas is unlocked.

In your code example canvas remains locked almost all the time and cause [starvation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/starvelive.html). There is only a little window for SurfaceFlinger to take a canvas a process it. So sometimes this code could fail and that's why ANR errors were sporadic.

Comment: Excellent! The second paragraph clearly describes the problem! Thank you!